# Restrict Column length in Oracle SQL Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dblink

Currently we created DBLink in Oracle database schema from where we try to write SQL query on Microsoft SQL Server database table. We want to create View based on this Select query.

For some tables from Microsoft SQL Server database tables the select query runs fine in Oracle database schema usign dblink.

But for some tables the sql query is throwing below error :

```
[Code: 600, SQL State: 60000]  ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [HO define: Long fetch], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

This are caused by `nvarchar(max)` columns where the column length is more than `4000 char` in Microsoft SQL Server database table.

Below are the sql query where `exceptionreason` is `nvarchar(max)` column and is having length more than `4000 char` in Microsoft SQL Server database table and which is causing issue in Oracle Select query.

```
SELECT  id
      ,queueid
      ,keyvalue
      ,status
      ,attempt      
      ,exceptionreason
from AEvents@Bsm_MSSQL;
```

Is it possible to restrict the column length for field `exceptionreason` for example to `4000 char` in Oracle Select query so that we can avoid the above issue ?

Comment: You mean with [the `substr()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html)? Or does that not work for you for some reason? (Multi-byte characters could be a problem...)

Comment: that is an internal oracle error code and you need to contact oracle support

Comment: @AlexPoole not sure how substr works here. For example in mysql server if we use Left([exceptionreason],4000) in select query it will restrict the length and the query works fine. So something similar in Oracle select query

Comment: Would CAST do any good? Something like `cast(exceptionreason as varchar2(4000))`

Comment: There's a reference in [an AskTom article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536421900346563332) to getting ORA-02070 in a similar scenario, so getting ORA-00600 may be a bug; but the comments include a example of chopping the remote column into 1k chunks (not 4k, to avoid multibyte issues) and those could then be concatenated into a varchar2 or CLOB on the Oracle end - you'd need some limit on the number of chunks you want to deal with though.

Comment: Also [see this Oracle support note](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1224783_1.html) about this issue, if you have access to My Oracle Support; that has more information and workarounds.